# PHP echo only 1 higher or 1 lower then current hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, echo, hour

So I'm having this issue where I want to echo only the things that are 1 higher or 1 lower then the current hour. Example if current hour = 14 only echo 13, 14 and 15

Anyone have a clue on how I can do this?

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("*******", "******", "**");
if(!mysql_select_db("deb67423_dj")) {
die("<b>Mislukt!</b><br>Het verbinden met de database is mislukt.");
}
$textweek = date("D");
if($textweek == "Mon") {
$dag = 0;
} else
if($textweek == "Tue") {
$dag = 1;
} else
if($textweek == "Wed") {
$dag = 2;
} else
if($textweek == "Thu") {
$dag = 3;
} else
if($textweek == "Fri") {
$dag = 4;
} else
if($textweek == "Sat") {
$dag = 5;
} else
if($textweek == "Sun") {
$dag = 6;
}
$textuur = date("G");

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM rooster WHERE dag = '$dag'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<td> Hiervoor: DJ ".$row['gebruikersnaam']. "</td>";
}                   
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What does the code have to do with your question?

Comment: This is what I have so far, but I have no clue on how to go further.

Comment: 1. Do you have a timestamp in your database? 2. Why aren't you using an array instead of 7 if sentences? 3. Why aren't you using `$dag = ((int)date("N") - 1);` instead?

Comment: Oh, and: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

```
$currHour = date('G');
echo $currHour - 1, ', ', $currHour, ', ', $currHour + 1;
```

Take note that `$currHour` can be 0 and you will have to take care of this "special" case... But I think this snippet will get you started. See the PHP [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation for more help.